# Find a generator of the ideal $I = ⟨x^4 + x^3 − 3x^2 − 5x − 2, x^3 + 3x^2 − 6x − 8⟩ ⊆ \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> Recall that every ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a principal ideal. Find a generator of the ideal $I = ⟨x^4 + x^3 − 3x^2 − 5x − 2, x^3 + 3x^2 − 6x − 8⟩ ⊆ \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

My general idea was that in order for something to be a generator of $I$ it must be able to generate both $x^4 + x^3 − 3x^2 − 5x − 2$ and $x^3 + 3x^2 − 6x − 8$
If you were able to find a common factor between the two of them, the multiplication of those factors would produce the generator of the ideal. I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: Are you familiar with [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)?

Comment: You're on the right track. Do you know Euclid's algorithm?

Comment: @m_t_ i am familiar.  would it be correct to say that x^2 -3x + 2 generates the ideal? Since (x-1)(x-2) are both common factors. I am unsure how to check if it is right.

Comment: what you need to do is to find the greatest common divisor of the generators of $I$, which you can do with Euclid.  You can show that an ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ is equal to the principal ideal $(\operatorname{gcd}(f,g))$.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the comments, by using the Euclidean algorithm we compute that
$$
d=gcd(f,g)=x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x+1).
$$
So the ideal $I$ is generated by $d$. Note that your $x-1$ is not a linear factor.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is simple because it is easy to decompose into factors the polynomials:
$$x^4 + x^3 − 3x^2 − 5x − 2= (x-2)(x+1)^3\\
x^3 + 3x^2 − 6x − 8=(x-2)(x+1)(x+4)$$

We have $(x-2)(x+1)$ a common factor. So any polynomial in the ideal is divisible by $(x-2)(x+1)$, in other words, the ideal is contained in the ideal generated by $(x-2)(x+1)$. To show that it is equal, we need to show that $(x-2)(x+1)$ is in the ideal. Equivalently, we need to show that $1$ is in the ideal generated by $(x+1)^2$ and $(x+4)$, which is true-- for instance we have
$$(x+1)^2=(x+4-3)^2= (x+4)^2-6(x+4)+9$$ so
$$1 = \frac{1}{9}(x+1)^2-(\frac{1}{9}(x+4)-\frac{2}{3})(x+4)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have good answers; this is just about an algorithmic approach for the extended Euclidean algorithm that mimics continued fractions

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 6 x  - 8 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 6 x  - 8 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) } +  \left(  9 x^{2}  - 9 x  - 18 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 6 x  - 8 \right)  =  \left(  9 x^{2}  - 9 x  - 18 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 4 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 4 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x  + 4 }{ 9 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{9 } \right)  -  \left(   x  + 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 2 }{ 9 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 6 x  - 8 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 4 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 5 x  - 2 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{9 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 6 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 2 }{ 9 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right)  $$